# CGContextFillEllipseInRect acting weird

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

Here is my `drawRect`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.bounds);
}
```

and the instances of this class are added a subviews the next way:

*(`#define DOTS_SIZE 30`)*

```
[self addSubview:[[VertexView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(anchor.x-DOTS_SIZE/2, anchor.y-DOTS_SIZE/2, DOTS_SIZE, DOTS_SIZE)]];
```

As far as I understand, I should get and ellipse *(circle my case)* in the views bounds. But I get it fully filled with rectangle *(square)*.

By the way, I have logged bounds and their size is 30x30, so I should get nice little circles, but I get **squares** (T_T)

I'll be thankful for any advise!

Comment: You should post more code and preferably the complete `drawRect` method. The problem is not in the line you posted.

Comment: @sch I've edited my question, but anyway there is only one method in my `drawRect`. I just need to set a circle to represent vertex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have to make some setup before drawing the ellipse. For example:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor); // Or any other color.
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, self.bounds);
}
```

And to make background transparent you can check out: [Setting A CGContext Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125543/setting-a-cgcontext-transparent-background)

Comment: wow. that's really a solution, but why this views start with black background? Their superview starts with white. And my first implementation was to just draw circles instead of instantiating the subviews. That's why I was confused, because I've thought that all views start with a white background

Comment: Yes, views has a property `backgroundColor` that is initially equal to the white color. But when you implement `drawRect:` the background color is not taken into consideration and you are responsible for drawing your view.