# How do you add a textview to a image view?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've been researching this question but the answer I found does  not work.

```
[myImageView addSubview:myTextView];
```

I want the text to become part of the image, so if I saved myImageView to the camera roll, the text would be included.
Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13522413/1730272. This is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you've already got a UIImage img, then use the following code to add texts

```
-(void)drawText:(NSString *)text onImage:(UIImage *)img
{
   UIFont *font = yourTextViewFont;
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
   [img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1);
   [text drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(20, 20) withFont: font];

   UIImage *ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return ret;
}
```