# DrawRect keeps drawing white background

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, drawrect, cgpath

```
//inside init
_color = [UIColor orangeColor];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;

//inside drawRect
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx,
                                   _color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

The background keeps showing up as white rather then transparent. The ellipse also does not change color and shows up as black. Thank in advance to anyone who takes a look.

Comment: Is your view's opaque property turned off?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it's off and it still does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refer to this answer for your transparency issue :
[Setting A CGContext Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125543/setting-a-cgcontext-transparent-background)

As for your ellipse color issue, it correctly display as an orange ellipse on my simulator so you may check at possible overlays or other possible side effects from other parts from your code.

Comment: I was being a moron and I set the background to clear in the init but not in awakeFromNib. But thanks for your speedy response.