# UIView Background Color Always Black

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

When I add a `UIView` to a View Controller programmatically I am not able to change the background color to any other color, it always remains black.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 33)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 33)];
    path.lineWidth = 5;
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

When I comment `drawrect:` out and add `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];` to the initializer the color changes:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]
    }
    return self;
}
```

Why is this and what do I need to change? Actually I would like the background to be transparent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`backgroundColor` of your view is ignored if you draw view yourself using `drawRect`. Change your code to

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];  // changes are here
    UIRectFill(rect);               // and here 

    UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 33)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 33)];
    path.lineWidth = 5;
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

Comment: Answer works perfectly when I want a background color. But I cannot use [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];  It still comes out black.

Comment: @Pete, I see the same result as you do when trying to set the color to clear in drawRect. To fix that, delete that UIRectFill call and set the background color to clear in the view's init method (which ever init method is appropriate for the way you create the view).

Comment: @Pete Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125543/setting-a-cgcontext-transparent-background. Maybe it will help

Comment: @Pete Also check that your view's `opaque` property is NO. i.e. `your_view.opaque = NO`.

Answer (score 36):

As you are implementing `drawRect:` this will override any default drawing of the `UIView`.

You must set the `opaque` property of your custom view to `NO` and clear the context before you render the path:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.opaque = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

    UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 33)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 33)];
    path.lineWidth = 5;
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/opaque

> An opaque view is expected to fill its bounds with entirely opaque
>   content—that is, the content should have an alpha value of 1.0. If the
>   view is opaque and either does not fill its bounds or contains wholly
>   or partially transparent content, the results are unpredictable. **You
>   should always set the value of this property to NO if the view is
>   fully or partially transparent.**

Comment: When I use this command, the background remains black for some reason. Solution does not work for me. Why could this be?

Comment: I've corrected my answer. It's important to set the opaque property of the view to NO.

Comment: Why it doesn't work any more, as along as I clear the rect before drawing, the result view will have a black background, whether `isOpaque` set to `true` or `false`.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set the background color in initWithFrame: method and do your custom drawing inside drawRect:. That should be able to solve your problem. The drawRect: is implemented in order to do custom drawing not to set view specific properties.

```
@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
      self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 33)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 33)];
    path.lineWidth = 5;
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];

}

@end
```

Comment: This is what worked for me swift 5

Answer (score 1):

```
backgroundViewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
backgroundController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[overlayViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
```

or

[image]

I struggled for many hours . If its a model segue, set  over current context as property. !